# how to clean or convert unknown characters in an otherwise integer field in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a data set by downloading data from disparate sources. The source files are all excel files. I am using pandas data frame to accomplish this. After writing the compiled file to a .csv file, I noticed that some of the cells in the dataset has unnatural characters in it. For example, in a field with all integer values, one cell has value `1,05â€¢6`. Upon checking in the data frame, I see that the same cell is read in as `'1,05\xe2\x80\xa26'`.

How do I convert these back to integer if it is possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you use `read_excel`? does it read it in correctly?

Comment: when I am doing `print  df.iloc[320,1]`, it is giving me`1,05•6` but without the print statement it is giving me `'1,05\xe2\x80\xa26'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what is the «expected» value of the cell. If it should be `1,056` then you can use this approach:

```
val = ''.join(c for c in val if c.isdigit() or c in ',.')
```

This can also be expressed in functional style:

```
val = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c.isdigit() or c in ',.', val))
```

And if all «trash» characters should be just removed then use something like:

```
from itertools import takewhile
val = ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: c.isdigit() or c in ',.', val))
```

In all these samples I suppose that decimal separator allowed is any of `,` or `.`.

Comment: It sounds like it will work for now. But I am really intrigued. Right now I have few thousands rows and I can scroll through and check, but with millions of rows, how do I find out ? any thoughts ? thanks

Comment: Well, it depends on your original data. I think you should check it once and then choose proper approach for all rows. Is that bullet character `•` present in the Excel file?

Comment: If all rows have the same situation then you can just use this comman in a loop for thousands or millions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that bullet is present in the excel file. Unfortunately, only few cells has this, but they are buried deep in the file, hard to notice. In this particular case, I pretty much eyeballed it after trial and error, but with millions of rows, I am not sure how to fish out these types of erroneous entries. Any thought.

Comment: Do you want to just remove these bullets? If yes then just use last code sample from my reply (with `takewhile`) and pass *all* incoming data through it. That way you will make sure that only digits and commas are present in the data.
Alternatively, you can make a script which will report all «suspicious» cells: `for i, cell in enumerate(my_cells): if not all(map(lambda c: c.isdigit() or c in ',.', cell)): print("Strange cell %d: %s" % (i, cell))`
It will help you to check (and maybe fix) all strange cells.